# Can I use as dependent variable a percentage in a linear multiple regression model?

Tags: regression, linear

I'm trying to model percentage of recovery (pain intensity) after surgery. The median is higher than 50% and the upper quartile 89%.

If normality of residuals and linearity between variables along with the other assumptions is maintained, can I use % as the dependent variable?

Comment: Usually beta regression is used when the response variable is a proportion.

Comment: You can use logistic regression especially if there are any 0 or 100% values in the data; beta regression will not work. If you want to stick with standard linear regression when modeling proportions, I'd be more concerned about whether the predicted probabilities exceed the 0-1 interval. If they don't, given a large enough sample size, robust standard errors might just be sufficient for reliable inference, and your results might be useful for learning about the data.

Comment: I have some 100% values in the data...Other than linear regression, what model do you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered fractional logit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not.

When you have a model: $$ Y = X \beta + \epsilon $$ where you assume $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, you are assuming that $Y$ itself is normally distributed. In fact, you are assuming that $Y \sim N(X \beta, \sigma^2)$.

We check the residuals to see if there is evidence of non-normality. We do this because usually, we don't actually know the underlying distribution of $Y$. However, here, you know that your dependent variable is constrained between $(0,1)$. Remember, the normal distribution is not constrained between $(0,1)$.

Comment: What option do you suggest to deal with this? I tried to do binomial regression, but I'm loosing information when the variable is binarized..

Comment: You could use beta regression. I see above that you have some data at the boundary - so you could try a one-inflated beta regression model.